# Configure JHipster to use local linux sendmail

Tags: linux, spring, centos, sendmail, jhipster

I'm new to JHipster and just trying to set up a dev environment on an AWS instance.

```
sendmail user@xxxxx.com < mailtest.txt
```

works from the command line so I know my local sendmail is working.

Looking through the configs in 8080/#/jhi-configuration there is a default spring.mail user of "" (empty string) and a default password. Is there a trick to this I am missing?

Comment: Have you read the doc? https://jhipster.github.io/tips/011_tip_configuring_email_in_jhipster.html

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Yes, I have read that document. The document discusses how to connect to an smtp server that is external to your server host. I am trying to connect to the local sendmail server and that is not working.

Comment: It should be the same as for any java application, nothing specific to JHipster. So please show your mail application properties and describe what you have tried.